# In a package or parasitic class, when is it better to redefine a command and when is it better to define a new one?

Tags: best-practices, package-writing, documentclass-writing

When I'm working on a document for which I need special layout, I tend initially to accumulate a very long preamble. At some point, if I need to reuse similar layout regularly, I decide that I really ought to tidy things up and create a custom class or package. If a class, it is typically a parasitic one i.e. it loads another class so I don't have to worry about missing important stuff out.

In some cases, I am now in a situation where I have custom commands which are operating not unlike standard commands. For example, I might be using something like this rather than using `\section` for the `article` class:

```
% Note that this is definitely not an MWE! 
% My question is specially about code which makes little sense outside
% a very specific context. If the code did make sense on its own, I would
% not need to ask the question. 
% BEGIN defn \ns
  \NewDocumentCommand\ns{sO{}}{%
        \gdef\thiss{#2}%
        \setcounter{ssn}{0}%
        \IfBooleanTF #1
          {%
                \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
                #2}%
          {%
                \stepcounter{sn}%
                \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\S\thesn\hspace*{1.5em}#2}%
                \S\thesn\hspace*{1.5em}#2}%
          }
% END defn \ns
% BEGIN defn \nst
  \NewDocumentCommand\nst{sd()O{}md<>O{}O{}sd<>}{% \nst*(frame width)[graphics options]{image file}<caption>{section title}{subsection or other subheading}<additional source/copyright/attribution>
        \clearpage
        \pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
        \begin{titlingpage}
          \AddThispageHook{\usebox{\mysecsglas}}%\input{../../secs/secs-glas}%
          \noindent\sffamily\bfseries\color{bcol1}%
          \begin{center}
                \vspace*{\fill}
                \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
                  {%
                        \includegraphics[#3]{#4}}%
                  {%
                        \efbox[#2]{\includegraphics[#3]{#4}}}%
                \IfNoValueTF{#5}{\relax}{\medskip\\\normalfont #5}%
                \bigskip
                \vspace*{\fill}\vspace*{\fill}\\
          \end{center}
                \hspace*{\fill}%
                \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
                  \nsfont\ns*[#6]}{%
                  \nsfont\ns[#6]}%
                  \vskip -.5em
                  \stepcounter{ssn}%
                  \hspace*{\fill}{\nssfont #7}
        \end{titlingpage}
        \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
          \setcounter{ssn}{0}
          \vspace*{\fill}\vspace*{\fill}\begin{center}
                  Sealing wax\IfBooleanTF{#8}{, cabbages}{} and kings courtesy Lewis Carroll.\smallskip\\
                  \IfNoValueTF{#9}{\relax}{#9\smallskip\\}
                  Typeset using pdf\LaTeX, {B{\sc \uppercasesc i\kern-.025em \uppercasesc b}\kern-.08em\LaTeX} and Biber in Latin Modern and URW ChanceryL.
          \end{center}
          \cleardoublepage}
% END defn \nst
```

On the one hand, these commands are used in my document as replacements for `\section`. (Probably it would be closer to use `book` or `report` and say it is being used like `\chapter`. But actually, I'm using `article` because that's how it started.) They set the title, add stuff to the ToC and so on.

On the other hand, these kinds of commands are also radically unlike the standard commands as they do a whole bunch of other things and are designed for a much more specific purpose.

I'm wondering whether best practice would involve redefining the standard commands and using `\chapter` or `\section` or whatever. Or whether best practice would involve leaving those commands alone.

Note that I'm aware that either will work. Also, this is much too tailored to ever be of interest to anybody else so I am not asking about the wisdom or otherwise of inflicting any version of this on anybody else ever. (Doing so would clearly be idiotic.) I'm more thinking of what will be best from the point of view of maintaining and updating the code for my own use in the future.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks. I'm also not sure the question is entirely clear. Could you say more about what isn't clear? I found it rather difficult to put together. (But maybe that means that I'm not clear what I want to ask.)

Comment: It's parasitic. Nothing really matters :)

Comment: +1 for the description "parasitic".  (i've been calling these things "derivative", but i may switch.)  would you ever want to use *both* the conventional `\section` *and* your alternative structure in the same document?  if yes, then definitely define a new command/environment.  if no, and they are functionally equivalent, then i'd see justification for using the same name.  are you certain you'll never see any reason to inflict them on anyone else?  then it really doesn't matter.  (but if i were doing it, i'd most likely use new names.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. It would actually be convenient to have `\section` as well. However, I'd probably have to redefine `\section` to make it work. Right now it is an uncomfortable mixture of my own commands at the top level and then `\subsubsection{}` on from the standard ones. I can use `\section*` but using `\section` messes things up (especially the ToC) so I have to remember not to use `\section`/`\subsection`. I can't imagine I would ever inflict them on anybody else, no. Nor can I imagine anybody allowing me to!

Comment: Maybe the right way would really be to define two levels above `section` and set the ToC not to include anything from `section` down... Hmm... I hadn't thought of doing it that way before.

Comment: When I do this I usually `replace` the standard commands. This has the advantage that, first, the document is easy to read (in five years time will you remember what `\ns` does?) and, secondly, it will still compile if you later switch to a "standard" (non-parasitic) class. If this is purely for your own amusement - that is, you never intend to make your parasitic classes public - then it really doesn't matter either way.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. I'm actually even more certain not to try compiling this with a standard class than I am never to inflict the code on anybody else. The documents I'm using this for just would not make sense with any standard class I'm aware of. (It they did, I probably wouldn't have grown such an icky preamble;).)

Comment: This is kind of tangential to the question as asked, but the `\nst` command might really benefit from a key-value approach. At least then when you use it in a document, you can understand what each part does / should do without referring back to the command defintion. More to the point, I tend to try to 'refactor' my weird/personal command definitions periodically. What I've 'learned' from doing so is to *not* try to recompile old documents when I really need to be finishing my current project! I've often been burned by 'just checking something' only to spend two hours making the old doc work.

Comment: @jon I've never had much luck with key-value interfaces. Is there one in particular you'd recommend?

Comment: Well, in truth, I'm not the right person to ask.  I've fiddled with `keyval`, `pgfkeys`, `yax`, and `l3keys`, but I've only really ever used the last two.  (And note that while `yax` is neat, it is sort of taking you out of the LaTeX world, which is not necessarily a bad thing, but it is a thing worth noting.)  However, if you want some key-value abilities without as much of the programming, there's also the `keycommand` package.  Obviously, if you like `xparse` -- and who doesn't? -- then there's something to be said for sticking with `l3keys`.

Comment: @jon Thanks. Maybe I'll look at `l3keys`. I've tried `keyval` and `xkeyval` in the past and found them difficult to understand and use. (I've managed to use bits in the end but it felt like trial-and-error even though I read the documentation. Almost certainly a failure on my part.) I've used `pgfkeys` a little with `tikz` but, even there, I end up with commands like this where I have to remember which options go in which order so I can't pretend to have succeeded in using it properly! I've never heard of `yax` or `keycommand`, though...

Answer (score 4):

As you seem to be concerned with `\section`, I'll make a couple of examples.

The `memoir` class allows for *two* optional arguments to `\section`, one for the TOC entry and the other one for the header. In the KOMA-script classes `\section` has just one optional argument which should contain a list of `key=value` pairs (it also allows just the short version of the title as in the standard classes for back compatibility).

For both the standard call is `\section{...}`.

Lamport's dream was to design his system so that simply changing the document class would typeset a document in a wide variety of formats. Alas, this proved to be impossible. For instance, the AMS classes *want* that the abstract is typed before `\maketitle`, for very good reasons. In the standard classes this would lead to a disaster. Other classes require specific commands for their various purposes.

The same AMS classes have a very interesting feature like `\only` (not very well documented, though) for deciding what parts of a section title are to go in the TOC and what are to go in the header, solving the problem in a different way from `memoir`.

Every time one uses additional features, the document will not be processable by the standard classes any more. So it's not generally possible to transfer a document from `memoir` to `book`, so the slight change in the syntax of `\section` is the least of the problems.

In my opinion, a class or package writer should be concerned with *the user*. If the syntax of `\section` is not really different from the “standard” one, call the command `\section` and don't think twice. On the other hand, if you'd like to change `\section` to have, even for some good reasons, *two* mandatory arguments, don't do it: users will almost surely forget one. Call the command `\sectionx` or whatever you deem sufficiently distinctive so that users will know they should do something different than usual.

Another example. Suppose your publisher wants that quotations are in italics: this is a case where redefining the `quotation` environment to change font *is* good. Providing a differently named environment would confuse users for another reason: they will continue to use `quotation` and the copy editor will live some nightmares.

Note that among the users *you* are included, especially if the class is for your personal use. You'll experience double personality problems when you need to use `\section` with the two mandatory arguments when the class is your own and the plain old `\section` when submitting a document to someone else.

A final example. In `memoir` when you say `\listoffigures`, the list will automatically be included in the table of contents and one can use `\listoffigures*` for not doing this inclusion. The AMS classes do the same but don't have a way to avoid the inclusion. Good: this is something the standard classes *should* have been endowed with in the first place, but unfortunately the idea wasn't considered. The problem with `memoir` is that `\tableofcontents` also adds itself in the TOC and one must remember typing `\tableofcontents*`. This is, in my opinion, a very bad error: it's like adding the inventory to the inventory. Nobody wants to be told, when reading the table of contents what page the TOC starts in: it's like instructions that say "for pushing button A, start pushing button A”.

Always remember the users of your class or package: don't force them to do bizarre mind twisting exercises.