# How to check if a macro from <some package> is used in a document?

Tags: macros, packages

I was interested in some method to check if any macro from some package is used into a .tex file.

So, for example I would like to specify a package (say it's `fontawesome`) then point to a .tex file and ask if any macro from the given package can be found in that .tex file.

Is it possible?

Comment: Comment out the package an look for errors :-) Seriously: once macros are defined there is no sense of where they 'come from'. (I suspect we've been asked this before.)

Comment: Add `\tracingmacros=1` at the start of the LaTeX document and then check whether the macro you're interested in appears in the `.log` file. All macros of `fontawesome` start with `\fa` (of course a search for this might give several false positives.

Comment: Create an empty file named `fontawesome.sty` in the same folder and compile your `.tex`. No need to modify your `.tex` file.

Comment: @egreg this only works assuming you are already searching for some specific macro, right?

Comment: @Carlitos Yes, of course. My usual policy is to add a package to my document only when I'm sure I need it.

Comment: @Symbol1 clever! I'm going to test it, thanks.

Comment: @egreg you are absolutely right, but as I learn more I tend to remove old code that now doesn't look right anymore. But sometimes I forget the source of some macros, so I tend to stack packages that I don't use anymore but I'm afraid of removing because I don't know if are still used for something or not.

Comment: @Carlitos Some time or later you have to do the giant step. ;-) I too, at the beginning, tended to load every macro I had used before (no packages, at the time I used Plain or AMSTeX), but soon realized I didn't even remember what some of the macros did, no matter if comments told it: it had become too long to scan the macro set.

Comment: @Symbol1 Your suggestion worked well, if you make an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) Comment the line loading the package that you want to test:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
The  \faBook  
And  
the \faCloud
\end{document}
```

(2) Compile from the command line `yourfile` in `nonstopmode`:

```
lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode yourfile
```

With the above MWE you will see in the output that now lines 4 and 6 have undefined macros:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 The \faBook

! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 the  \faCloud
```

Enabling the package there are no errors, *ergo* these commands are defined in that package (or through that package, as the egreg's comment pointed).

Note that these error messages are also stored in `yourfile.log` for later forensic analysis. Probably your favorite LaTeX editor can compile and show the ouput/log errors directly  (only the first without `nonstopmode`) so you do not have to deal with the command line.

Comment: `\usepackage{mathtools}` and `\boxed`: remove the package and the command is undefined; but `\boxed` is not defined by `mathtools`. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg, Certainly,  I should have advised that there [parasitic clasess](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201566/in-a-package-or-parasitic-class-when-is-it-better-to-redefine-a-command-and-whe) and parasitic packages. In your example one could say that is a "nested definition" trough  `\RequirePackage{amsmath}[2000/07/18]` that load  `\newcommand{\boxed}[1]{\fbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}}`, but  from the practical point of view (e.g., prevent not working macros  due to removed package) this is mainly irrelevant.